# C# HttpClient - can I force close the connection?

Tags: c#, iis, dotnet-httpclient

We are seeing an issue where a customer is hitting our API and cancelling the request before it completes.  We believe that they are also closing the connection so the requests are not getting written to the IIS logs.  I'm trying to create a runner to duplicate this behavior.  What I can't figure out is ***how can I force close the connection so that the server cannot send data back?***

Here is my current code:

```
 private static async Task RunMe()
    {

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(5000);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-apikey", "some key");
                Console.WriteLine("making request");
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync("https://foo.com/api/apitest/testcancel", cts.Token))
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Request completed: {result}");
                }
            }
            finally
            {                    
                client.CancelPendingRequests();
                Console.WriteLine("about to dispose the client");
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code correctly cancels the request after 5 seconds but IIS still seem to send back data after the API call completes (set to 10 seconds).

How can I close the connection so that IIS cannot send back any data after my 5s timeout?

Comment: Just use a socket and slam the door after sending the request.

Comment: @CodeCaster that seems like a good plan.  I tried an example here but it's not sending any data.  Do you have a sample that works with https?

https://gist.github.com/jayhilden/ea6603adb22c36daeae6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to duplicate the problem by using raw sockets, which is a lot of work.  The way to get IIS to log the cancelled requests is to do the following in the code below:

1. do NOT send `Connection: Close`
2. do NOT call `Socket.Dispose()`

Here is the final working code, hopefully someone else will find this useful:

```
private static void SocketTime(int readTimeout, Random random)
        {
            var ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            const int hostPort = 80;

            var hostep = new IPEndPoint(ip, hostPort);
            var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sock.Connect(hostep);
            var uniqueID = random.Next().ToString();
            var get = $"GET http://localhost/api/apitest/testcancel/{uniqueID} HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                      "x-apikey: somekey\r\n" +
                      "Host: foo.com\r\n" +
                      "Connection: Close\r\n" +
                      "\r\n";


            var getBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(get);
            sock.ReceiveTimeout = readTimeout;
            sock.Send(getBytes);

            var responseData = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                var bytesRead = sock.Receive(responseData);
                var responseString = new StringBuilder();
                while (bytesRead != 0)
                {
                    responseString.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(responseData), 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = sock.Receive(responseData);
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"SUCCESS => Unique ID = {uniqueID}, Timeout = {readTimeout}");
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"FAIL => Unique ID = {uniqueID}, Timeout = {readTimeout}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UNHNALDED ERROR: " + e.Message);
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                sock.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hit by a very low timeout setting. If you set it to a sufficiently short amount of time, the client will close the connection although the server still tries to return data.

If this doesn't reproduce the problem you could also look into concurrency and the property 'UseNagleAlgorithm' on the servicepoint manager. This property being true attempts to pigiback several small http requests in the same TCP package. It is a band with saver, but causes client timeouts as the os delays sending data through the socket until it has gathered enough data.

Comment: _"several small http requests in the same TCP package"_ no, Nagle has no notion of application protocols. Nagle can cause headers and body of one message to end up in the same packet, for example, just by waiting for more data until it has enough to send a full packet - or until a preconfigured timeout occurs.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference. I don't claim it knows about http, but I have seen problems related to the exact behavior you describe as the client calculates its timeout from the initiation in the application but the actual network communication is started after a delay waiting for more data. As this is transparent to the application it reports a network timeout that isn't obvious if you look at the network traffic.

Comment: An HTTP 1/1 client will not send the next request over the same connection until the previous response was received. :) So if request 1 is still in the send buffer, the application won't have received the response and thus not issue request 2. Your remarks on Nagle are spot on, I just don't think it can cause two HTTP requests to be in one packet. :)

Comment: The default config for most OS network stacks is for Nagle to coalesce up to 2 TCP segments where the combined total will not be greater than the MTU and will wait no longer than 100ms. If your client is timing out after 100ms, you have other issues. This can create issues for web requests smaller than an MTU as it will add a 100ms delay.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling Dispose on the response object instead?

Check out this post:
[Force connection to close with HttpClient in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968657/force-connection-to-close-with-httpclient-in-wcf)